# Find out current table element border-spacing in GWT 2.8.2

Tags: css, html-table, gwt

I have an element that has been created via `DOM.createTable()`, which creates a simple `<table>` element without `cellspacing`. When I inspect that element in Chrome, I can see that it has the default style `border-spacing: 2px` that comes from the user agent stylesheet. And in some of my application themes that value has been overridden with `border-spacing: 0`. The computed styles for the element don't show `border-spacing`, but there is `-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 2px` (or `0` if using an overriding theme) that points back to the `border-spacing` style.

I'm curious, how could I check at run-time what the current spacing value is?

Here are some of my attempts to print the value to console (the first set in particular is pretty obvious since I haven't called `setCellSpacing` -- if I had, the first option would of course return that value):

- `((TableElement) element.cast()).getCellSpacing()` -- empty String
- `element.getStyle().getProperty("cellspacing")` -- undefined
- `element.getPropertyInt("cellspacing")` -- 0
- `element.getStyle().getProperty("border-spacing")` -- `Error: java.lang.AssertionError: The style name 'border-spacing' should be in camelCase format`
- `element.getStyle().getProperty("borderSpacing")` -- empty String
- `element.getPropertyInt("borderSpacing")` -- 0
- `element.getPropertyInt("border-spacing")` -- 0
- `element.getStyle().getProperty("webkitBorderHorizontalSpacing")` -- empty String
- `element.getPropertyInt("webkitBorderHorizontalSpacing")` -- 0
- `element.getPropertyInt("-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing")` -- 0

These values don't change whether I use `border-collapse: collapse` or `border-collapse: separate`, but of course only the latter actually displays the spacing. The computed `-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing` value also doesn't change in either case.

If I try this in Firefox, it naturally doesn't have the webkit style, or even default `border-spacing` style, but if I set it in a theme it does display the `border-spacing` itself in computed styles. Still didn't give me any usable values with an incomplete selection of the calls listed above.

I'm clearly missing something pretty basic here.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to read spacing value too early, before the `table` is actually rendered. Try use deferred reading: `com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(...);`.

Comment: It's a good thought, but the print is tied to a button click and I can print `offsetWidth` for the same element just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use elemental2 to get the element as an HTMLElement then get its CssStyleDecleration then get the property value

```
elemental2.dom.HTMLElement element = //get the element as elemental2 HTML element
String propertyValue = element.style.getPropertyValue("border-spacing");
```

make sure to use the elemental2 version that works with gwt 2.8.2, if the `style` property for HTMLElement is not available for that version of elemental2 you can always manually write the JsInterop to add it.